# Prevent from deleting the first paragraph inside a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript

I don't want to remove the first paragraph from the root div using the `Backspace` key. How can I prevent deleting the first or the only paragraph inside this contenteditable div? This paragraph should also editable. Javascript will help to prevent this paragraph. I need a idea.

```css
.root {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="root" contenteditable="true">
  <p id="block-1">I want to prevent this paragraph from delete.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: a little unclear to be honest. so you do not want this text `I want to prevent this paragraph from delete.` to be deleted via backspace  ? what if someone select this `I want to prevent this paragraph from delete.` and write something else ?

Comment: Yes. They can rewrite this paragraph or block-1 but not delete

Comment: @Md.Tahazzot, What if the rewrite involved deleting some characters?

Comment: Isn't this just another way of saying: "They must enter something but if they don't or if they delete what's there already, use this paragraph as default text"?

Comment: "I don't want to remove the first paragraph from the root div using the Backspace key" yet the accepted answer (and the other "working" answer) doesn't fulfil this criteria?

Comment: I am completely  baffled - how on earth you accepted answer which does not solve the problem according to this question ??? you said something else in question and does not want users to delete the paragraph text and i had clarified before i posted an answer

Comment: I said don't delete by pressing backspace, I didn't says that to stop rewrite someting else.

Comment: @Md.Tahazzot Oh, you are talking about the paragraph **tag**, you should have made that clear in your question, seems like a lot of people thought you were talking about the actual paragraph text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .root {
      max-width: 700px;
      margin: 1rem auto;
      border: 1px solid;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="root" contenteditable="true">
    <p id="block-1">I want to prevent this paragraph from delete.</p>
  </div>
  <script>
    const div = document.querySelector('.root');
    const paragraph = document.getElementById('block-1');
    div.addEventListener(
      'input',
      (event) => {
        if (!event.target.contains(paragraph)) {
          div.insertBefore(paragraph, div.firstChild);
        }
      },
      false
    );
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following event listener to the root element will prevent the backspace key from doing anything if all it can do is delete the first paragraph, which is the only time that it can delete the first paragraph. It starts by checking for the backspace key, but before preventing the default action from occurring, it will also check to make sure that there is no text and there is only one paragraph left. This works because paragraphs can only be deleted without text content, and you can't remove the first paragraph unless it is the only paragraph left.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("root")[0].addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.key == "Backspace" && this.textContent == "\n  \n" && this.children.length <= 1) {
    event.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

```css
.root {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="root" contenteditable="true">
  <p id="block-1">I want to prevent this paragraph from delete.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is also right. Thanks. But someone already has been write the ans before you.

Comment: The goal was to prevent the actual paragraph element from being deleted, not any of the text it contains. Both the accepted answer and this one achieve that goal.

Comment: @ThatComputerGuy Thanks, At least there is two person who understands what I actually ask for, Rest of them don't have mind or time to think and help someone newbie.

Answer (score -1):

You could add attribute contenteditable="false" either in html or with JS:

```
<div class="root" contenteditable="true">
    <p id="block-1" contenteditable="false">I want to prevent this paragraph from delete.</p>
    <p id="block-2">I do not want to prevent this paragraph from delete.</p>
</div>
```

or with JS:

```
let immutableP = document.getElementById('block-1');
immutableP.setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
```

Here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/willystyle/73naf4cx/9/).